# React testing library finByText exceeded timeout

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

Problem with findByText method in React Testing Library when using MaterialUI Autocomplete and mock service worker

I'm having an issue with the findByText method in React Testing Library. Specifically, I have a component called ExpertWall that renders users that I've mocked using MSW. Inside the ExpertWall component, I have a button to create new users, and when it's clicked, 3 inputs appear:

- sectionInput: a MaterialUI Textfield
- userRoleInput: a MaterialUI Textfield
- userEmailInput: a MaterialUI Autocomplete that queries the MSW for a user based on the entered email and returns it.

The problem occurs when I try to find the Autocomplete option for the user returned by MSW. I use the await screen.findByText() method to wait for it to appear in the DOM, but if I don't set the test timeout to 20 seconds with jest.setTimeout(20000) at the top of the test, I get a "timeout exceeded 5000ms" error. When I try with screen.getByText() then when I analys DOM with screen.debug() I got that autocomplete showing 'loading'

How can I resolve this issue and make the test run successfully without having to increase the timeout?

"The get and post methods are implemented in MSW. Unfortunately, I cannot show more code due to privacy reasons.

I would like to add that I am a junior and tried to describe the problem as best as I could."

```
it('should add new user to wall of expert ', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup({delay: null})
    customRender(<><AppSnackbar/><ExpertWall/></>)

    const openCreationWallOfExpert = screen.getByRole('button', {name: /open-creation-expert-wall/i})

    //Open box to creat a new user
    await user.click(openCreationWallOfExpert)

    const userSectionInput = screen.getByLabelText('Section')
    const userRoleInput = screen.getByLabelText('User Role')
    const userEmailInput = screen.getByLabelText('User email')

    const section = 'Test'
    const role = 'New user role'
    const email = 'test@test.com{enter}'

    // Add to input
    await user.type(userSectionInput, section)
    await user.type(userRoleInput, role)
    await user.type(userEmailInput, email)

    // Wait to get list from autocomplete and select it
    const userEmail = await screen.findByText('test@test.com')!
    await user.click(userEmail)


    //Add new user, it is mock also by msw which add new user to mock users.
    const addUserButton = screen.getByRole('button', {name: /add-new-user/i})
    await user.click(addUserButton)

    // get info that user added success
    const successMessage = "User has been successful added"
    expect(await screen.findByText(successMessage)).toBeInTheDocument()

    //refetch to get all data, it's fix by msw together with added msw endpoint
    fetch(`${apiurl}/experts/getAll`)

    expect(await screen.findByText(role)).toBeInTheDocument()
});
```

"What else did I do to make the code work? As I mentioned, I tried to add jest.setTimeout(20000), but I'm not sure if it's a good solution. The code works and executes, but is it bad for performance?

I was thinking about using useFakeTimers, but I don't know how to use them in my case."

More data: MSW that is the handlers which I did as documentation and then started the server in test beforeAll. I can add that the getAll is all users. getByEmail is for autocomplete component and add to add new user.

```
export const handlers = [
rest.get(`${apiurl}/experts/getAll`, (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(mockWallOfExperts));
}),
rest.get(`${apiurl}/person/getByEmail/*`, (req, res, ctx) => res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(mockUserInformation))),

rest.post(`${apiurl}/experts/add`, (req, res, ctx) => {
    const newUser = req.body as any;
    mockWallOfExperts.push({ ...newUser, id: 999 });
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(req.body));
})];
```

This is AutoComplete for getting user email.

```
export const UserAutocompleteField = (props: UserAutocompleteProps) => {
const { t } = useTranslation();
const notify = useNotify();
const classes = useStyles();

const [getPerson, result] = useLazyGetPersonQuery();

const checkUserExistInOptions = (newUser: PersonDTO) => {
    return props.options.some((user) => user.name === newUser.name);
};

const fetchUser = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const currentTarget = e.currentTarget.value;
    getPerson(currentTarget, false)
        .unwrap()
        .then((user) => {
            if (checkUserExistInOptions(user)) return;
            props.setOptions((prevState) => {
                return [...prevState, { ...user }];
            });
        })
        .catch(() => {
            notify(t('maintenance.infoTexts.cant-find-user-message'), 'error');
        });
};

const textFieldOnChange = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    if (e.key !== 'Enter') {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    fetchUser(e);
};

const autoCompleteOnChange = (
    e: React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>,
    value: PersonDTO | null,
    reason: AutocompleteChangeReason
) => {
    if (reason === 'selectOption' && value !== null) {
        props.getUserInformation(value);
    }
    if (reason === 'clear') {
        props.clearUser();
    }
};

return (
    <InputLabel>
        <Typography>{t('maintenance.infoTexts.user-email-address')}</Typography>
        <Autocomplete
            className={classes.autoComplete}
            options={props.options}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.email}
            noOptionsText={t(`DRW.labels.form-employee-search`)}
            // filterOptions is added to avoid warnings in console
            filterOptions={(personsData) => personsData}
            loading={result.isLoading}
            value={props.inputValue ?? null}
            onChange={autoCompleteOnChange}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    name="searchUser"
                    variant={props.variant ?? 'outlined'}
                    InputProps={{
                        ...params.InputProps,
                        endAdornment: (
                            <>
                                {result.isFetching ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
                                {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                            </>
                        ),
                        onKeyDown: textFieldOnChange,
                    }}
                />
            )}
        />
    </InputLabel>
)};
```

I added few logs to MSW to check if the request even come to msw and everything seem like it is.

Comment: It's worth noting increasing the timeout wouldn't help anyway. It's not that it's taking a long time; it can't see it because probably, for some reason, the data can't load from MSW, possibly due to incorrectly configured mocks. You need to show the actual app code that loads the data and also your mocks as well to help further. You mention you can't share this but sadly, it is needed. Maybe show a minimised or changed version?

Comment: One thing that would help you is to add logs in the actual fetching code in the app to see what happens to the network request and capture the errors.

Comment: @adsy Thank you for your response. I added a few logs to MSW to check if I'm reaching the endpoints, and I got everything. However, this is surely not enough. I also added some more code as mentioned.